# Multiple SKLightNodes don't work together

Tags: swift, xcode, graphics, sprite-kit

I have the following SpriteKit scene

If I enable one SKLightNode it looks ok like this:

[image: one light enabled]

If however, I enable both lights, the lights just mess up completely:

[image: two lights enabled]

Is this a bug in SpriteKit, is it a known limitation? - Am I missing anything here to get this to work?

Project file here: [Xcode Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjh5mhvupf8fiaa/SpriteKitLightTest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: show some code, something that other people can reproduce

Comment: I've uploaded the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the lights’ shadows are getting combined—notice how the only fully lit areas in your screenshot are the ones that can “see” both lights, and how there are darker shadows in the areas that can “see” neither. I’d [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Bugged as: 35721595